# What's the largest string OpenSSH can expand from a % token?

Tags: ssh, token

Instead of a traditional authorized_keys file on my server, I'm using a custom key verifier which sshd calls via the [`AuthorizedKeysCommand`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) option. In the sshd_config, I can specify that this command should be fed the user's public key as an argument, like so:

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /path/to/verifier %k
```

The problem is that the key encodes a lot of additional data and so can be quite large. If it's bigger than around 4135 bytes, sshd logs a fatal error while expanding the `%k` token:

```
sshd[5914]: fatal: percent_expand: string too long
```

I've been combing through the [source code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/947affad4831df015c498c00c6351ea6f13895d5/misc.c#L1384-L1396) of `percent_expand` and I don't see anywhere where this `string too long` error might be encountered. It appears that there is some kind of limit on the token size, but what is it? Where is it defined?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using an older OpenSSH version that happens to limit the entire expansion buffer to 4096 octets. Update beyond 8.1, which [you should, anyway](https://www.openssh.com/security.html).

The message you did not find in source code was removed in commit `switch percent_expand() to use sshbuf instead of a limited fixed buffer` - see [OpenSSH-portable](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/e3b6c966b79c3ea5d51b923c3bbdc41e13b96ea0) and [OpenBSD upstream](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/misc.c.diff?r1=1.139&r2=1.140&f=h)

Comment: I *think* the limit after that is close to the 256kiB maximum packet size (printed as "upload size" when calling `sftp -v`) - well beyond the expected cert size with allowed key sizes - which on OpenSSH-portable on Linux would stay below (base64-encoded) 2MiB `ARG_MAX` for command invocation.

Comment: Upgrading solved my issue! As for the absolute upper bound on later versions of OpenSSH, I've yet to hit it :)